# grunt concat doesn't concat all files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm using grunt-concat to concatenate all my files into one js file, however it appears to only include the first, and last 3 files. Missing out 3 files.

The concat section of my gruntfile.js is as follows

```
concat: {
    options: {
        stripBanners: true,
        seperator: ';',
    },
    dist: {
        src: [
            'headers.js',
            'otr/build/deb/salsa20.js',
            'otr/build/deb/bigint.js',
            'otr/build/deb/crypto.js',
            'otr/build/dep/eventemitter.js',
            'otr/build/otr.js',
            'userscript.js'
        ],
        dest: 'build/gmail-otr.js'
    }
},
```

The `build/gmail-otr.js` file only contains `headers.js, eventemitter.js, otr.js & userscript.js`

Has anyone else had this problem before?

Comment: You've written `deb` instead of `dep`.

Comment: @MMM Oh no, feel rather silly now!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo made by the person who asked the question. The specific problem and solution are unlikely to be broadly useful. (See this [meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions).)

Comment: Agreed, I cant delete it however as it has an answer now. Flagged it to be closed instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paths are incorrect. The files you're missing are using `deb` instead of `dep` in their path, so the tool can't find them.

Comment: Oh dear, such a silly thing to overlook.

Comment: @Bodyloss: No worries, it happens even to the best developers ;)